# Почему cookie не работает при регистрации?

Tags: php, cookie, сессия

Здравствуйте, я новичок в программировании. 
Весь вечер не могу решить проблему. В файле login.php имеется следующий код(срабатывает при входе, работает с таблицей: username, password, login):

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED);


$connect=mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('rash');

if (isset($_POST['enter'])) {
$e_login=$_POST['e_login'];
$e_password=$_POST['e_password'];
$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM WIreg WHERE login='$e_login'");
$user_data=mysql_fetch_array($query);

if ($user_data['password']==$e_password) {
$re=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM WIreg WHERE 'login'='$user'"); 
  $name=mysql_fetch_array($re);
setcookie('cookie_name', $name['username']);
  $_SESSION['cookie_name'] = $name['username'];
header("location: user/auth.html");
}
else {
echo "wrong password or login";
}

}
?>
```

Выводит всю страницу auth.html кроме имени username. 
Далее в файле auth.html (находится в директориии user)имеется следующий код:

```
<?  session_start(); echo $_SESSION['cookie_name']; ?>
```

Вопрос: почему не отображается username?

Comment: в html файле нельзя вставлять php код.......только в php и в phtml. Кстати, который может не отработать из-за short tags (имеется в виду открытие кода не через `<?php`, а через `<?`)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский в целом же можно настроить на сервере, почему сразу нельзя?

Comment: @teran я написал что может не отработать из-за этого (ибо ТС, как новичок, может этого не знать). Где я написал, что нельзя? Я  не запрещаю ничего.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я про php-код в html-файле :)

Comment: @teran ааа. так всё равно никто не делает. разве что избранные извращенцы)

Comment: @Полина Романова А где вы стартанули сессию в login.php?

Comment: до setcookie на страницу что-либо выводится?

Comment: @Полина Романова  login.php -> session_start();

Comment: @АлексейШиманский а знать, что так можно сделать, видимо, пограничное состояние, да? :D

Answer (score 0):

После проверки пароля вы делаете повторный запрос:

```
$re=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM WIreg WHERE 'login'='$user'");
```

Но переменная $user у вас ранее не определяется, поэтому данный запрос выдаёт пустой результат, соответственно и куки далее определяются пустые.

Учитывая, что вы ранее уже получили необходимые вам данные из базы (они у вас в переменной $user_data), предлагаю переписать последний if так:

```
if ($user_data['password']==$e_password) {
  setcookie('cookie_name', $user_data['username']);
  $_SESSION['cookie_name'] = $user_data['username'];
header("location: user/auth.html");
}
else {
echo "wrong password or login";
}
```

Но вообще хранить пароли в явном виде неправильно.